# Transform a list into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to have a pandas dataframe with data processed into a loop but i end up with a series.

here is my code:

```py
def generatevaral():
    data = []
    countindexmax = _VARS['-NBINDEX-']
    count = 0
    while count < countindexmax:
        TEST2  = 'EPP 7 = DASH 2'
        TEST3 = _VARS['-NBJOURS-']

        dfupdated = pd.DataFrame()
        dfupdated = df1.filter(items=['filenames', '[state_corrected_daily]','[state_corrected_daily]', '[dj_index]'])
        dfupdated = dfupdated.loc[(dfupdated['filenames'] == TEST2) & (dfupdated['[dj_index]'] == count)]

        dfupdated['calc1'] = ((dfupdated.iloc[:, 1] - dfupdated.iloc[:, 1].shift(1))**2)/2
        dfupdated['calc2'] = dfupdated.iloc[:, 4].cumsum()
        dfupdated['index_col'] = range(0, len(dfupdated) )
        dfupdated['calc3'] = np.sqrt(dfupdated.iloc[:, 5]/(dfupdated.iloc[:, 6]))

        
        dfupdated = dfupdated.loc[(dfupdated['index_col'] == TEST3),'calc3'] #
        
        count += 1
        data += [dfupdated]
    return print(data)
```

and here is the results:

```
[Series([], Name: calc3, dtype: float64), 842    0.0
Name: calc3, dtype: float64, 843    2.699541
Name: calc3, dtype: float64, 844    0.6453
Name: calc3, dtype: float64, 845    0.580266
Name: calc3, dtype: float64, 846    0.592017
Name: calc3, dtype: float64, 847    0.571797
Name: calc3, dtype: float64, 848    0.578003
Name: calc3, dtype: float64, 849    0.578827
```

I was expecting a dataframe of 1 columns with float values, does anyone understand what i'am doing wrong?

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example. Context and variables are missing here.

Comment: It's awkward, as you see, to build up a dataframe bit by bit.  Just create all of your data in a Python list, then convert that to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

To add one column of float value, you should be using `df.loc` like this, with only one float value to have in a single column:

```
# add row to end of DataFrame
df.loc[len(df.index)] = [floatvalue1]
```

Another option would be to use the `df.append` function.